# How to average positive inputs until a negative input is given

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How can I accept and average positive numbers? When a negative number is entered, it should terminate the loop and display the average (excluding the negative number).

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std ;
int main () {
    int x,counter=0,sum;
    float avg;
    while (x>0) {
        if(x<0) {
            sum+=x;
            counter++;
            continue;
        } else if  (x>0) {
            cin>>x;
            sum+=x;
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    avg=(float)sum/counter;
    cout<<avg<<endl;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: @arcyqwerty: OP's original question seemed to contain an explicit reference to `continue` being used. From his comments below, it seems to me that he insists on using `continue`. Maybe this should be reintroduced into the question.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: If that's the case I'm happy to edit that back in and update my answer.
@KhaledAdel: Do you require the use of `continue` in your solution or is any working solution valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int sum = 0, count = 0, input;       // initialize all variables
  while (true) {                       // loop forever (until break is reached below)
    cin >> input;                      // get user input
    if (input < 0) break;              // if it's negative, exit loop
    sum += input;                      // otherwise add it to the running sum
    count++;                           // increase the count by 1
  }
  if (count > 0) cout << (double)sum / count;   // if we have at least one number, display avg
  else cout << "No numbers to average" << endl; // else complain.
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this will fail if the user provides bad input. If you need it to handle bad input, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) about cin types.

Comment: You should have to input something (even if it's junk/nonsense) on your keyboard before it breaks out of the while loop...

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that you have immediately adds the input to your sum.

```
int main () {
int x,counter=0,sum;
float avg;
while (x>0) {
    cin >> x;
    if  (x>0) {
        sum+=x;
        counter ++;
    }
}
avg=(float)sum/counter;
cout<<avg<<endl;
return 0 ;
}
```

This would allow you to check the input before adding to your total.

It is also important to mention to avoid dividing by zero if the user's first input is a negative number.

Comment: `while (x > 0)` is not guaranteed to be true when x is uninitialized.  Should set `x = [nonzero]` in declaration or use `while (true) {... if (x < 0) break; ...}`

Comment: Similarly `sum` may contain garbage leading to incorrect results.

Comment: i tryed this before but i need to understand how can i make it with continue statmen  ur answer is good to bro

Comment: Why do you insist on using `continue`? Isn't the point solving your problem? That is probably easier without `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

here is an improved version, that checks if loop exist without any positive integers entered to avoid divide by zero error

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main () {

    int x;
    float counter=0,sum;
    float avg;

    bool isPositive = true;

    while ( isPositive) {
            cin>>x;
            if(x>0)
            {
                sum+=x;
                counter ++;
            }

            else {
                isPositive = false;
            }
    }

    // if we divide by zero, an error will occur
    if(counter > 0)
    {
        avg=(float)(sum/counter);
        cout<<avg<<endl;
    }
    else cout << "Please enter positive numbers";

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: @KhaledAdel  nan error is fixed in my code because it checks if there is no positive numbers entered before dividing, it should work without any errors now